# Windows 2012 Core - IIS8 - Shared Configuration

Tags: configuration, share, iis-8

I'm trying to setup windows 2012, IIS8 shared configuration. That is two IIS servers share the same configuration file which is stored on a network share.

I've setup a share and granted userA "full control" to the share. I've also granted the userA account "modify" permission to the file security.

I then ran the following VB script:

```vb
Set adminManager = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.ApplicationHost.WritableAdminManager")
adminManager.CommitPath = "MACHINE/REDIRECTION"
Set configurationRedirection = adminManager.GetAdminSection( "configurationRedirection", "MACHINE/REDIRECTION" )
configurationRedirection.Properties.Item( "enabled" ).Value = True
configurationRedirection.Properties.Item( "path" ).Value = "\\server\iis-config"
configurationRedirection.Properties.Item( "userName" ).Value = "ourdomain\userA"
configurationRedirection.Properties.Item( "password" ).Value= "password"
adminManager.CommitChanges
```

When I try and access the server via IIS Manager I get the following error:

```
There was an error while performing this operation.

Details: 
Filename: MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST

Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was able to figure this out on my own. Per the microsoft documentation:

*Note: If NT Service\WMSVC does not have permissions to the UNC share -- which will be the case for UNC shares on another machine -- (WMSVC means nothing outside the realm of a local machine), update the identity of Web Management Service (services.msc) to be a domain user that has access to the server as well as the UNC share.

So what I had to do is going into services.msc on each of the web servers and change the "Web Management Service" to run using my new domain account (ourdomain\userA) and now it all works.

Hope this helps someone else.